# Git cloning stucks on receiving objects

Tags: git, github

When I'm cloning from git repository it stucks on Receiving objects

```
Receiving objects:  13% (126/963), 22.08 MiB | 7.03 MiB/s
```

with command 'git clone https://github.com/Hadevs/GitPoliChat.git --verbose'

```
    Cloning into 'GitPoliChat'...
    POST git-upload-pack (155 bytes)
    remote: Counting objects: 963, done.
    remote: Compressing objects: 100% (569/569), done.
    Receiving objects:   8% (78/963), 2.55 MiB | 2.45 MiB/s
```

Also it's in Github Desktop

Thank you for help

Comment: Probably Internet problem.

Comment: How long have you waited? This can take some time, especially with larger repositories. Running `git clone` with the `--verbose` option should give you much more detail. Please try that and [edit] your question to include the new information. If you would prefer not to drop into the command line, please look for a debug log in the GitHub Desktop client that might contain the same information.

Comment: @D3nimyr, it looks like it's cloning just fine… please give it some time.