# Recieving objects too slow in Git

Tags: ios, git, git-clone

Before asking the question, I find a related post:

[Git cloning stucks on receiving objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38329376/git-cloning-stucks-on-receiving-objects)

But it seems it is fine, my Receiving objects is very slow.

[image]

Only 3.00 KiB/s, why it is so slow, because I am in China, the GFW affect?

I have tested open the VPN to turn over the GFW, and I can see facebook.com.

How to increase the internet speed when git clone ?

Comment: Maybe try use VPN i suppose

Comment: @Tj3n have tried. look at my post.

Comment: In many cases, found that the route from a user's ISP to our network (NTT) to be the issue.  More https://confluence.atlassian.com/bbkb/troubleshooting-network-issues-389778693.html

Comment: What if you use `git://github.com/user/repository.git` url?

Comment: I my case I recloned my repo to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000
```

or

```
git config --global http.proxy proxy-listen-ip:proxy-listen-port
git config --global https.proxy proxy-listen-ip:proxy-listen-port
```

or

```
git config --global http.http://github.com.proxy proxy-listen-ip:proxy-listen-port
git config --global https.https://github.com.proxy proxy-listen-ip:proxy-listen-port
```

if your operating system is linux,
use proxychains (google it):

```
proxychains git clone url
```

or
click this link [nslookup](http://tool.chinaz.com/dns?type=1&host=github.global.ssl.fastly.net&ip=),choose the response ip whoes ttl value is minimal.
[image]
in this case, choose 151.101.76.249.
then add the ip to /etc/hosts, like this:
[image]
save, and maybe you need to restart the machine

Then,maybe you can enjoy it.

Comment: I test your suggestion, now report fatal:`fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git/': Could not resolve proxy: proxy-listen-ip`

Comment: please replace proxy-listen-ip to your vpn ip  and replace proxy-listen-port to your vpn port ( if you use PPTP, that is 1723)

Comment: I listen my proxy ip, but still slow like tortoise, I don't know where is the issue.

Answer (score -1):

1. First of all have the very stable internet connection.
   Check the stability of your connection in fast.com
2. If you are accessing the client network with VPN, then obviously the download speed will be reduced for the client websites.

I faced the same issue many times, tried in different ways like tortoise git, Git bash and CMD prompt. Atlast high speed and stable connection resolved my issue.

you can also get the time to finish the clone by using the below command,

"time git clone URL"